# Element style inside jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

When I apply a style to a particular element all the elements inside that will automatically be affected by the style. 
How can I restrict style for a particular element inside my code?

My code is as follows:

```
$.each(result, function(i, item) {

tr.append($("<td/>").html('<label name="qty" class="name">'+item['ITEM_NAME']+'</label>')).css('color', '#819FF7');
tr.append("<td>" + item['QUANTITY'] + "</td>");
});

$('#tbl_items').append(tr);
```

And finally the html table

```
<table id="tbl_items"></table>
```

What I need is apply CSS `color` for only `ITEM_NAME` `<td>`

Is it possible? or which is the right way?

Comment: Can you give a generated html snippet with rows (where result of query is not NULL) !

Answer (score 0):

You can create the element you need in a line:

```
var e = $(item['ITEM_NAME']);
```

and apply alla you want to it:

```
e.css(...)
```

and then append it where you want.

In your code you're chaining actions and jQuery chains works always on the whole matched selector. Unless using `.find(...)` but in your example it will be unclear.

Comment: Thanks for your replay. But if i assigned to another variable like you did it will display [object Object]. Not getting the right value

Comment: I got the value in e but cant apply css like e.css :(

Answer (score 0):

You will have to apply css on particular element on on whole TR.

var items = ["Orange", "Apple", "Banana"];

```
$.each(items, function (i, item) {

    var tr = $('<tr>');

    var td = $('<td>').append($('<lable>').attr("name", "qty")
        .addClass("name")
        .text(item)
        .css('color', '#819FF7'));

    tr.append(td);

    tr.append("<td>" + item + " Quatity" + "</td>");

    $('#tbl_items').append(tr)
});
```

Check out this [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uoe5f3ab/)

Apply CSS conditionally.

```
  var td = $('<td>').append($('<lable>').attr("name", "qty")
            .addClass("name")
            .text(item);

  if(item == 'Orange'){
    td  = td.css('color', '#819FF7'));
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick replay Is it possible to add css color on either one item say Apple?

Comment: Yes. You can invoke method based on certain condition as well. Let me modify my answer.